# How can I write an event to the EventLog when a PowerShell script run as a Scheduled Task is cancelled?

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a long-running PowerShell script.  Sometimes it gets cancelled e.g. right-click > End in Task Scheduler. Is there any way to catch this so that I can write an event to an event log?

Comment: I'd suggest using a try/catch/finally block.  Catch can be excluded.  Finally will always be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on my comment, here's something you can do:

```
Try
{
    <# just script things #>
}
Finally
{
    New-EventLog ...
}
```

It won't catch that it was forcefully closed, but the `Finally` will always execute, so you can log when it does close/finish.

You could use some variable in the `Try` block to indicate whether it has completed processing and figure out logic in the `Finally` block from there.